# Is it possible to get only one property in eager loading?

Tags: c#, eager-loading, ef-core-2.0

I know that with select, I can load only few properties in EF Core, something like that:

```
var posts = context.Posts
                           .Where(p => p.Tags == "<sql-server>")
                           .Select(p => new PostDto() 
                           { 
                               PostId = p.Id, 
                               PostTitle = p.Title 
                           });
```

The problem is that I am want to load a related propertie with Include() and from this related entity I only need a property.

I am trying something like that:

```
dbContext.Posts.Where(x => x.IdPost = 2)
.Inlcude(x => x.States.IsEnded)
```

But I get an exception that says that IsEnded is not a navigation property.

So I would like to know how to select only one property when I use eager loading with Include().

Thanks.

Comment: Shortly - you can't.

Comment: Yes you can.  Just add it to your projection.

Comment: @Amy The way I read the question, OP knows how to use projection, but he wants to use *eager loading* (returning entity instances rather than DTOs).